# Zend Framework 2 magic quotes gpc

Tags: zend-framework

I'm trying to install the Zend skeleton application and when I run the command "php composer.phar create-project --repository-url="http://packages.zendframework.com" zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install" I get an error about magic_quotes being deprecated.  I'm using GoDaddy servers and I turned magic_quotes off in my php.ini file.  Any ideas what could be causing the problem?

Based on the error it looks like my the file in /web/conf/php5.ini has magic_quotes On for some reason.  It's a read only file that I can't change.  Shouldn't the file in the root of my server be changing the setting in it?

When I run phpinfo it shows magic_quotes_gpc and the other magic_quotes all as Off.  What could be causing this error message in ssh?

Could it be because my GoDaddy hosting account is running PHP 5.3.24?  The minimum on the Zend site says 5.3.3

Comment: You've probably edited the wrong `php.ini` file. Run a `<?php phpinfo() ?>` file and check the locations of any configuration files as well as the values for `magic_quotes_gpc`

Comment: I edited the php.ini in the root of my site with
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
and when i run the phpinfo it says magic_quotes_gpc ON  I looked further in the php.ini file and there are no other instructions to enable magic_quotes.

Comment: I now have magic_quotes_gpc showing an 'Off' status in my phpinfo, but I'm still getting this error in ssh.(I tried logging out and logging back in too)

PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /web/conf/php5.ini on line 1256 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /web/conf/php5.ini on line 1257 in Unknown on line 0

Deprecated: Directive 'magic_quotes_gpc' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0